# Get the contents of a HTML tag via parsing

Tags: c#, string, split, html-parsing

I need to split this/similar string to get the **VALUE**

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0);" id="def_" name="color" rel="ml">VALUE</a>
```

I can do *String.Split(">")* and then another *StringArr[1].Split("<")* but that is not efficient and bulky.

What would be the way way to do it?

Comment: Look into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) since you aren't parsing a string but HTML

Comment: Are you only interested in *this specific task* or are there other parsing scenarios?  Parsing HTML is not trivial and you should use established methods if this isn't a one off sort of thing where you know *exactly* what the input will look like at all times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a *parser*, trying to split the string would be just a temporary hack. Look into [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

For your example HTML this would like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(inputHtml);

var text = doc.DocumentNode
              .Descendants("a")
              .Where(x => x.Attributes["id"]!=null && 
                          x.Attributes["id"].Value == "def_")
              .First()
              .InnerText;
```

Comment: <3 I love this approach with LINQ style

Answer (score 3):

you can use an array, like

```
split(new char[]{'<','>'}
```

example

```
"<a  href='javascript:void(0);' id='def_' name='color' rel='ml'>VALUE</a>".Split(new char[]{'<','>'})
```

returns a result, like

```
a  href='javascript:void(0);' id='def_' name='color' rel='ml'  
VALUE 
/a
```

This is a general solution for the problem. If you are going to work hardly with `HTML`, *do not use* this way, but use specific `HTML` parsers.